# Receiving error 404 when trying to enroll an identity using Voice Recognition API

Tags: c#, azure

Receiving the following exception when trying to enroll a voice recording

```
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=One or more errors occurred.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at SpeakerRecognition.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\marti\OneDrive\Desktop\speakerrecognition-master\CS\SpeakerRecognition\SpeakerRecognition\Program.cs:line 27

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    SpeakerRecognition.IdentificationHelper.CreateEnrollment(string, string) in IdentificationHelper.cs

Inner Exception 1:
FlurlHttpException: Call failed with status code 404 (Not Found): POST https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/spid/v1.0/identificationProfiles/{"identificationProfileId":"764cb4ea-779c-453e-8eed-4201e07de6eb"}/enroll
```

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: Oops - sorry, I didn't think you'd need to see the code for a 404 error.  Apparently, the end-point is not being found - why would that be if the ms endpoint should be valid?